# OkHttpClient request witjh JSON body and POST parameters

Tags: json, post, okhttp

I am trying to make a request using OkHttp3 with 2 post parameters and a body.

```
//My Body
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{
\"grant_type\" :\"client_credentials\" }");

//Post Paramters
FormBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("Consumer Key", "name")
            .add("Consumer Secret", "password")
            .build();
```

How can I post both the body and the post parameters to my request?